# How to get the resolution of a bitmap image?

Tags: c

[Image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35gA3.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
void main() 
{
    FILE* infile;
    infile = fopen("img.bmp", "rb");
    
    BITMAPFILEHEADER Header_File;
    fread(&Header_File, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, infile);
    if (Header_File.bfType != 0x4D42) exit(1);
    
    BITMAPINFOHEADER Header_Info;
    fread(&Header_Info, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, infile);
    printf("Image Size: (%d x %d)\n", Header_Info.biWidth, Header_Info.biHeight);

    printf("biXPelsPerMeter: %d \n", Header_Info.biXPelsPerMeter); 
    printf("biYPelsPerMeter: %d \n", Header_Info.biYPelsPerMeter);

    fclose(infile);
}
```

The code I programmed is to get the resolution of an image. However, some images do not work properly.

I think this is because there is no vertical and horizontal DPI in the header information.

So, if there is no resolution in the header information of the image, the values of `biXPelsPerMeter` and `biYPelsPerMeter` are 0.

Is there any other way besides getting the resolution from header info?

Comment: The header tell you the width and height in pixels. Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: If the bitmap doesn't have a resolution then it doesn't have a resolution. Are you expecting to conjure one out of thin air?

Comment: thank you for the reply.
In summary, I would like to know how to get the DIP of an image.

Comment: Photoshop tools say the image source has a dpi value of 72.
I also asked the same question in other communities
One member said that you can get DPI without a header file, but I didn't explain it specifically, so I'm posting a question here.

Comment: Not really related but Photoshop very likely tells you the the image has 72 **PPI**, not DPI. It is pixels per inch, not dots unless you are directly involved in printing.

Comment: How many dots/pixels per inch depends on the medium where it is printed/displayed. It only makes sense in relation to a *scanned* image.